# How to solve Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML') at printTime when trying to show current time with JS and html

Tags: javascript, html

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsein.jpg)

```
function printTime() {
  let clock = document.getElementById("clock"); // use dom to choose a place for the clock
  let curr = new Date();
  let currtime =
    curr.getFullYear() + "/" + (curr.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + curr.getDate();
  clock.innerHTML = currtime;
  setTimeout("printTime()", 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
  printTime();
};
```

It seems like the time displays correctly but I am curious
why am I getting this error:
lab6.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')
at printTime

when I also added
`<div id="clock"></div>`in the HTML code?

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is working fine here

```js
function printTime() {
  let clock = document.getElementById("clock"); // use dom to choose a place for the clock
  let curr = new Date();
  let currtime =
    curr.getFullYear() + "/" + (curr.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + curr.getDate();
  clock.innerHTML = currtime;
  setTimeout("printTime()", 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
  printTime();
};
```

```html
<div id="clock"></div>
```

Comment: It was working fine I think. However, I wasn't just sure why I was getting the error at 
```clock.innerHTML = currtime;```
saying Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you get the error because the element is not yet rendered on the `window.onload` . Instead you should be looking for `body.onload` , or in other words, if you would set the call to `printTime` directly in the body tag, it would work fine.

```
<body onload="printTime()">
```

In any case, wrapping the `printTime()` inside an arrow function also works without the error :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <script>
      function printTime() {
        let clock = document.getElementById("clock"); // use dom to choose a place for the clock
        let curr = new Date();
        let currtime = curr.getFullYear() + "/" + (curr.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + curr.getDate();
        clock.innerHTML = currtime;
        setTimeout("printTime()", 1000);
      }

      window.onload = () => {
        printTime();
      };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="clock"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```